# AVFilterGraph error when uploading a video on MediaWiki

Tags: php, ffmpeg, mediawiki

I'm trying to implement videos on my wiki - dedicated server under debian - using the extension TimedMediaHandler.

I installed all the packages needed (I think) and I chmod 777 ffmpeg and ffmpeg2theora.

I'm running MediaWiki 1.31. I also put in my LocalSettings.php:

```
$wgMaxShellMemory = 512000;
$wgMaxShellFileSize = 1024 * 512;
$wgMaxShellTime = 60 * 60;
```

I can upload successfully and image's thumbnails are generated properly. But when I upload a video I get this error:

> Error creating thumbnail: '/usr/bin/avconv' -threads 1 -ss 33 -y -i
>   '/var/www/wiki_games/images/a/a8/DBD_-_Game_Intro.webm' -ss 3 -s
>   854x480 -f mjpeg -an -vframes 1 '/tmp/transform_6c1de80a29b2.jpg' 2>&1
>   wgMaxShellMemory: 512000 ffmpeg version 3.2.9-1~deb9u1 Copyright (c)
>   2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18)
>   20170516 configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb9u1'
>   --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared libavutil 55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101 libavcodec 57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101 libavformat 57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
>   libavdevice 57. 1.100 / 57. 1.100 libavfilter 6. 65.100 / 6. 65.100
>   libavresample 3. 1. 0 / 3. 1. 0 libswscale 4. 2.100 / 4. 2.100
>   libswresample 2. 3.100 / 2. 3.100 libpostproc 54. 1.100 / 54. 1.100
>   Input #0, matroska,webm, from
>   '/var/www/wiki_games/images/a/a8/DBD_-_Game_Intro.webm': Metadata:
>   encoder : Lavf57.71.100 Duration: 00:01:12.56, start: -0.007000,
>   bitrate: 1114 kb/s Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p(progressive),
>   854x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 427:240, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
>   (default) Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
>   (default) [AVFilterGraph @ 0x562cb5f6f6e0] Error initializing
>   threading. [AVFilterGraph @ 0x562cb5f6f6e0] Error creating filter
>   'null' Error opening filters!

My debug file shows:

```
Creating video thumbnail at /tmp/transform_a558a5a34268.jpg
File::transform: Doing stat for mwstore://local-backend/local-thumb/a/a8/DBD_-_Game_Intro.webm/854px-seek=36-DBD_-_Game_Intro.webm.jpg
Creating video thumbnail at /tmp/transform_bc23be9e4649.jpg
[exec] MediaWiki\Shell\Command::execute: /bin/bash '/var/www/wiki_games/includes/shell/limit.sh' ''\''/usr/bin/avconv'\'' -threads 1  -ss 33 -y -i '\''/var/www/wiki_games/images/a/a8/DBD_-_Game_Intro.webm'\'' -ss 3  -s 854x480 -f mjpeg -an -vframes 1 '\''/tmp$
[thumbnail] Removing bad 0-byte thumbnail "/tmp/transform_bc23be9e4649.jpg". unlink() succeeded
```

What do I need to do make the thumbnail feature works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "error initializing threading" makes me think it's the memory limit, try bumping that up.

Comment: Bumped memory_limit = 512M in php.ini, same issue. :/

Comment: Thanks! Setting $wgMaxShellMemory = 780000; in LocalSettings.php worked. Is it normal creating a thumbnail from a 9MB webm video takes that amount of memory?